# New page gets resources correctly but Edit page is not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a customer model which created by scaffolding. I got the _form.html.erb page which got some javascript plugins references. new.html.erb page works great but edit page is not. I see tons of errors like in edit.html.erb(in console) :

`Loading failed for the <script> with source http://localhost:3000/customers/assets/js/custom.min.js.`

(All missing files in _form.html.erb file)

This is my new.html.erb file:

`<%= render 'form', customer: @customer %>`

And this is my edit.html.erb file:

`<%= render 'form', customer: @customer %>`

JS references is on the bottom of the _form.html.erb file(inside of the body tag).

```
<script src="../assets/plugins/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="../assets/bootstrap/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
<script src="../assets/js/custom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Where have you placed that `.js` file? The problem is that the browser can't find that script

Comment: It is inside of the body tag on the bottom. New.html.erb works but edit is not.

Comment: Can you show us a line(s) in which you load the script (in both :edit and :new partials)? Have you tried in different browsers?

Comment: I tried both firefox and opera. Added the lines to main post.

Comment: In order for your script to load it would have to exist at `public/assets/customers/assets/js/custom/min.js`

Comment: Also this type of relative file loading will likely break in production. Please take a look at the asset pipeline or rails webpacker. You should be using javascript_include_tag or javascript_pack_tag

Comment: @Msencenb i got a huge html file. If i try to convert everything to rails style  , it would took thousands years.

Comment: @NMPennypacker it did not worked. I don't get it how it's working on new page but not in edit page.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the source references to :

```
<script src="/assets/plugins/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

made both of them worked.